# BUGS/JAGS for Nominal Response Model

Tags: jags, bugs, item-response-theory, categorical-data

I am a beginner with BUGS/JAGS and I was hoping to gather the opinion of you, experts.

I am trying to implement a Nominal Item Response Analysis (Polytomous, not ordered, like a multiple-choice exam) with JAGS. I simulated data according to this model, but 
the code doesn't seem to work as it can't recover the true parameters.

Here is the model and below is my attempt:

$P_{ijk}(Y = k | \theta_{i}, \alpha_{j,k}, \delta_{j,k}) = \frac{\exp(\alpha_{j,k} (\theta_{i} - \delta_{j,k}))}{\sum_{h=1}^{m}(\exp(\alpha_{j,h} (\theta_{i} - \delta_{j,h})))}$

where:

i = i-th subjects
j = j-th item
k = k-th alternatives (multplice choice)

I am aware of the code available for similar problems but I couldn't find anything specific for the Nominal model.

Can you please:

- point me to the problem in my code
- or suggest me where I can find snippets of BUGS/JAGS code

Many thanks in advance

J.

```
    for( i in 1 : nSubj )
    {
            for ( j in 1 : nItem )
            {
                    for ( k in 1 : nAlternatives )
                    { 
                        prob[ i , j , k ] <-  exp( -alpha[ j , k ] * ( theta[ i ] - delta[ j , k ] ) ) )

                    }
            }
    }

    for ( i in 1 : nSubj )
    {
            for ( j in 1 : nItem )
            {
                    for ( k in 1 : nAlternatives )
                    {

                        PI[ i , j ] <- ( prob[ i , j , k ]/(sum( prob[ i , j ,  ]))

                    }
            }
    }

    for ( i in 1 : nSubj )
    {
        for ( j in 1 : nItem )
        {

            y[ i , j ]  ~ dcat( PI[ i , j ] )

        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps post your code for generating simulated data; if you have any rjags code for calling the function, and what error messages you are getting.